# Fedora 38: need persistent changes in nsswitch.conf

Tags: fedora, dns, nsswitch

I've got Fedora 38 KDE Spin.
To access corporate VPN resources in .local zone I need to make queries to the DNS server after establishing connection.
Default nsswitch.conf hosts section looks like this:

```
hosts:      files myhostname resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
```

If I modify it this way:

```
hosts:      files myhostname resolve dns [!UNAVAIL=return]
```

Everything works as I expect. The problem is I can't make these changes persistent. Text in the file banner says:

```
# Generated by authselect
# Do not modify this file manually, use authselect instead. Any user changes will be overwritten.
# You can stop authselect from managing your configuration by calling 'authselect opt-out'.
# See authselect(8) for more details.
```

Not much info unfortunately. I've found [a manual for the authselect tool](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_authentication_and_authorization_in_rhel/configuring-user-authentication-using-authselect_configuring-authentication-and-authorization-in-rhel#modifying-a-ready-made-authselect-profile_configuring-user-authentication-using-authselect) in RedHat documentation, but it seem to be inapplicable for Fedora.
Here is what is sais:

```
Select an authselect profile, for example:
# authselect select sssd

Edit the /etc/authselect/user-nsswitch.conf file with your desired changes.

Apply the changes from the /etc/authselect/user-nsswitch.conf file:

# authselect apply-changes
```

I don't have */etc/authselect/user-nsswitch.conf* file in my system.
If I make one I don't know what content should it have. I tried

```
cat /etc/authselect/user-nsswitch.conf 
hosts:      files myhostname mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve dns [!UNAVAIL=return]
```

and then run `sudo authselect apply-changes` as said in the manual, no luck.

Can't find anything to solve this issue.
I would be very grateful to any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Fedora 38 it's `/etc/authselect/nsswitch.conf` instead of `/etc/authselect/user-nsswitch.conf` and it's content is the same as regular `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.
Then `authselect apply-change` will generate `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Interesting, but in /etc/authselect/nsswitch.conf the line looks exactly as I need it to be:
hosts:      files myhostname resolve dns [!UNAVAIL=return]

But after sudo authselect apply-changes the resulting /etc/nsswitch.conf is:
hosts:      files myhostname resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns

Probably it is Cisco Secure Client messing with the config.

Comment: you should be able to verify what is done through `authselect apply-changes --trace`

Comment: Don't know what happened, but everything works as expected after a reboot. If I'll find something new I'll update the question.